# How to put my console application dll in logic apps scheduler instead of Web jobs?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-logic-apps, azure-scheduler

Previously we create app serivce and in that by selecting web jobs we created schedulers by uploading dll zip.Now azure is retiring schedule web jobs.It is replaced now by logic apps.How to schedule my app now?
i.e.,how to put my dll in logic apps

Comment: There should be no impact to your webjobs they retired Azure Scheduler on September 2019 not Scheduled webjobs.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: I scheduled the application using cron expression.Still i have one more doubt will this  impact any cost for using ? I used an existing app service for this web job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing Azure web jobs and Azure Scheduler are different. As correctly said by Kamran, your system will not be impacted as you are using Azure web jobs.

Also Azure Scheduler already retire on 30th September 2019. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/azure-scheduler-will-retire-on-september-30-2019/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to know logic app is a cloud service that helps you schedule, automate, and orchestrate tasks, business processes, and workflows when you need to integrate apps, data, systems, and services across enterprises or organizations.  It doesn't run dll file, you could use it to connect other service without code. About how to migrate scheduler to logic app you could refer to this doc: [Migrate Azure Scheduler jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps).

Then if you want to run dll file on azure, the scheduler is totally retired, you could choose to use azure webjob or azure function. They both support [cron expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions) to do a schedule job.

About how to develop webjob you could refer to this doc:[Develop and deploy WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs) and here is the doc about how to develop azure function:[Develop Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs)

Comment: I understood now.Thanks!

Comment: If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.